Table is not showing data from dbsqlite3
I'm touching upon the problem with SQLite3 in Tkinter.
Table is not showing data from database.
Program is inserting data in database, but not showing them in the tree of table in tkinter.
I opened database.db file and data is inserting correctly.
In the images: the current state of the program and how much work it requires.

My code is:(lab.py)
def add_to_treeview():
    employees = database.fetch_employees()
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    for employee in employees:
        tree.insert('', END, values=employee)

def insert():
    id = id_entry.get()
    name = name_entry.get()
    role = role_entry.get()
    gender = variable1.get()
    status = status_entry.get()
    if not (id and name and role and gender and status):
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Enter all fields.')
    elif database.id_exists(id):
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'ID already exists.')
    else:
        database.insert_employee(id,name,role,gender,status)
        add_to_treeview()
        messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Data has been inserted.')

style = ttk.Style(app)

style.theme_use('clam')
style.configure('Treeview', font=font2,foreground='#aaa',background='#000',fieldbackground='#313837')
style.map('Treeview',background=[('selected', '#1A8F2D')])

tree = ttk.Treeview(app,height=15)#9)

tree['columns'] = ('ID', 'Name', 'Role', 'Gender', 'Status')

tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=tk.NO)
tree.column('ID', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=120)
tree.column('Name', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=120)
tree.column('Role', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=120)
tree.column('Gender', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)
tree.column('Status', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=120)

tree.heading('ID', text='ID')
tree.heading('Name', text='Name')
tree.heading('Role', text='Role')
tree.heading('Gender', text='Gender')
tree.heading('Status', text='Status')

tree.place(x=300,y=20)#60,y=20)

add_to_treeview()

app.mainloop()

database.py:
import sqlite3

def create_table():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Employees.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employees (
            id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            name TEXT,
            role TEXT,
            gender TEXT,
            status TEXT)''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def fetch_employees():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Employees.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employees')
    employees = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return employees

def insert_employee(id, name, role, gender, status):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Employees.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Employees (id, name, role, gender, status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',
                   (id, name, role, gender, status))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()



Does print(employees) show what you expect?

There is missing function id_exists() in database.py.  Apart from that, your code works fine.
